# Editing, commenting and reputation

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments, edits

What is the logic behind the feature where you can edit other people's posts, but you are not able to make comments of those posts? I know the edit will be reviewed before it is accepted, but still I think this is a bit stupid. I have failed to find an explanation for this from the FAQ.

I find it really irritating to not be able to participate in the discussion to get some additional information if I do not have an answer yet. I think the reputation cap for commenting should be at the same level when you are able to propose edits. It would make more sense to me that way.

Comment: Oh and now I got a priviledge to comment anywhere on this board? This is confusing. :(

Comment: For commentting on meta site you require only 1 Reputation while on main site Stack Overflow, you require 50 Reputation to comment anywhere

Comment: You can always comment on your own posts.

Comment: Yes I know I can comment on my own posts. The point is, I do not understand why the reputation cap for commenting is higher than priviledge to propose an edit.

Comment: since edit will be approved by other 3 user (>=2k rep)   so chances are less for someone to spam .. while there is nothing like for comment .. however they can flag comment btw you can see privileges here  http://stackoverflow.com/privileges

Comment: @Lasse - And you have now earned that privilege. Happy commenting :)

Comment: @hims056 Yes I noticed. Thank you :) The new problem is that now I actually have to think before commenting. :P

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think this is  (at least) twofold.

In the first place, setting a requirement of 50 reputation for leaving comments helps prevent spam (automated or otherwise).

In the second place, not being able to leave a comment as a user under 50 rep helps you understand the goal of Stack Exchange: to have clear, concise and helpful questions and answers without any noise or useless information. By making the ability to set comments a privilege, they make you think twice before commenting. "Is this *really* useful?" "Will it *really* add something helpful to the discussion?"

Comments are *not* meant  for discussing side issues, for thanking users, for asking question, for answering questions, etc etc.

Making it a privilege to leave comments helps keep the noise to a minimum. It sure makes me think before leaving comments.

Something to note is that it isn't hard to get 50 reputation. Giving one question a great answer will get you that easy. Or two OK answers. Or 25 edits. It isn't hard.

### TL;DR:

Comments on SE are different than comments elsewhere. The 50 reputation requirment for leaving comments is to prevent abuse of the feature. We aren't here to talk, we're here to solve problems.

<sup>Note: On Meta sites discussions are allowed. You'll see a fair amount of joking and noise throughout them. [They even have memes.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta)</sup>

Comment: Reversal cometh.

Comment: This pretty much answerred the question. Especially the part "Comments on SE are different than comments elsewhere." This is something I have to learn here. :)

Comment: @Lasse Yes, SE is a *very* diverse place. And very different too. Every site has a [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), an [about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) and [a chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) (not to mention meta sites) where you can ask questions about how we work. It may seems  a little harsh at first, but keep at it and you'll be fine :)

Comment: *...keep the noise to a minimum* That's curious. I thought answers could generate more noise. <50 rep users, can't comment, which is understandable, but still can post answers. In fact, are forced to post answers instead of comments when they have something to say. There has to be another reason for that policy besides noise, I guess.

Comment: @faa They are not forced to post answers instead of comments. They should just not do anything. Like I said, it isn't hard to get 50 rep. Posting comments as answers will likely get you answer banned.

Answer (score 2):

You need just 50 reputation to add comments because no one want to see their inbox full with SPAM comments. If anyone (including anonymous) can add comments then this can be an open treasure for spammer. Also earning 50 reputation is not a big deal. So this restriction is enough to prevent from spammers.

Talking about editing (suggested edits), anyone can suggest good edit so we allow anonymous to suggest edits. If a spammer suggests edits it will be definitely rejected by our community. And some rejected edit will block spammer from suggesting edits.

Comment: There will still be spam in my inbox if everyone and their cousin edits my post. But I understand the logic here now.

Comment: @Lasse You only get notifications about edits to your *answers*, otherwise it's just asking you to review a sub 2k users edit. See the [edit privelege](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit).